# What is the geometric proof for the Cartesian formula of the gradient

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis

In general, I have a good understanding of what the gradient is. Also, given the cartesian formula of the gradient, I can transform it into different coordinate systems. I am also familiar with the general, tensor-based definition, as partial derivatives contracted with the contravariant basis.

However, every explanation I have seen starts by defining the gradient as the vector whose dot product with any other vector gives the directional derivative along this second vector. And then, we get the Cartesian formula for the gradient, $\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{j} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\vec{k}$, from which we can do everything else.

What I still can't figure out, is how this Cartesian formula is derived. I assume that this is fundamentally a geometric problem. Is there a proof showing how to derive the Cartesian formula for the gradient? Or is it more like an educated guess that you can later prove that it has the desired properties (i.e it points in the direction of greatest increase, and it gives you the directional derivative when doted with a vector)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Cheers
Michael

Comment: *How* is this a [tag:proof-writing] question?

Comment: Please show more precisely where you disagree with the formulas.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I don't disagree with these formulas. There is nothing wrong with them. I just don't know where they came from. So I am asking if there is some proof

Comment: But which formulas exactly ?

Comment: The formula for the gradient in Cartesian coordinates. I've edited the question to include the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$Let's say for definiteness that $f$ is a real-valued function of three variables, defined in some neighborhood of a point $x_{0}$. (The story holds with obvious modifications for any number of variables.)

The  "primitive" concept is "differentiability": We say $f$ is *differentiable* at $x_{0}$ if there exists a linear function $L$ of three variables satisfying
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0}) - Lh|}{|h|} = 0.
$$
One straightforwardly shows $L$ is unique, and introduces the notation $Df(x_{0}) := L$.

The matrix of $Df(x_{0})$ with respect to the standard basis has the partial derivatives of $f$ as components, more-or-less by definition of a partial derivative:
$$
Df(x_{0}) = [\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
    D_{1}f(x_{0}) & D_{2}f(x_{0}) & D_{3}f(x_{0}) \\
\end{array}] = \Bigl[\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
    \frac{\dd f}{\dd x}(x_{0}) & \frac{\dd f}{\dd y}(x_{0}) & \frac{\dd f}{\dd z}(x_{0}) \\
\end{array}\Bigr].
$$

Because of how linear functions work (which amounts to the chain rule here), if $v = (v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3})$ is a vector, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} f(x_{0} + tv)
= Df(x_{0})v
&= v_{1} D_{1}f(x_{0}) + v_{2} D_{2}f(x_{0}) + v_{3} D_{3}f(x_{0}) \\
&= v_{1} \frac{\dd f}{\dd x}(x_{0}) + v_{2} \frac{\dd f}{\dd y}(x_{0}) + v_{3} \frac{\dd f}{\dd z}(x_{0}).
\end{align*}

This expression may be interpreted as a Euclidean dot product. We're led to give a name to the resulting vector $\nabla f(x_{0})$, a.k.a. the transpose of $Df(x_{0})$. That's "where the gradient comes from".

As for properties of the gradient, they follow from the preceding equation and properties of the dot product. If $\theta$ is the angle between $\nabla f(x_{0})$ and $v$, the *directional derivative* of $f$ at $x_{0}$ along $v$ is
$$
D_{v}f(x_{0})
= \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} f(x_{0} + tv)
= \nabla f(x_{0}) \cdot v
= |\nabla f(x_{0}|\, |v| \cos\theta.
$$
For $|v|$ fixed, $D_{v}f(x_{0})$ is maximized when $\theta = 0$ ($v$ is positively proportional to the gradient), miminized when $\theta = \pi$ ($v$ is negatively proportional to the gradient), and $0$ when $\theta = \pi/2$ ($v$ is orthogonal to the gradient).

Comment: Very useful information. Thanks. However, the main part that I am having difficulty is how you deduced that $\mathcal{D} f(x_0)$ has partial derivatives as its components. Similarly, if instead of the standard basis you use a different basis (e.g. the covariant basis of spherical coordinates), could you deduce the components of the gradient without going through the standard basis first?

Comment: A linear transformation $L$ is uniquely determined by its values $Lv_1$, $Lv_2$, $Lv_3$ on a basis. Here, given a vector $v$, we take $h = tv$ and let $t \to 0$, so $\frac{1}{|tv|}|f(x_0 + tv) - f(x_0) - tLv| \to 0$. Particularly, if $v=e_i$ is a standard basis vector then $Lv = \lim\limits_{t\to0} \frac{1}{t}[f(x_0+te_i)-f(x_0)]$ is the $i$th partial derivative. <> Given an arbitrary basis, we'd similarly deduce the components of $L = Df(x_0)$ in that basis, as you say, but to get the gradient we'd also need to express the dot product in that basis.

Comment: In your last sentence, where does the product come into play? Would $Lv = \lim\limits_{t\to0} \frac{1}{t}[f(x_0+te_i)-f(x_0)]$ change in any way  if $v$ was any arbitrary basis vector? Wouldn't it still be the partial derivative with respect to the coordinate corresponding to that basis vector?

Comment: The term "partial derivative" is reserved for a derivative with respect to one of the variables in terms of which $f$ is expressed. Other than that, yes, the difference quotient you wrote is effectively the same as a partial derivative. Some people would call it a "directional derivative", others require $|v| = 1$ when they use the term "directional derivative".

Comment: Nice. Just to clarify, in your initial answer, up to the application of the chain rule, everything would look the same regardless of the coordinate system.  Then we interpret the resulting expression of the chain rule as the dot product between the gradient of the function and the "velocity" vector. The different forms of the gradient in different coordinate systems arise because we need to include scaling factors so that the dot product between the basis vectors, along with these scaling factors, result into the expression of the chain rule. Is my understanding correct? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The gradient summarizes the variation of a multivariate function, to the first order. Let us move around $p=(x,y,z)$ in an arbitrary direction $q=(u,v,w)$ and compute the variation.

By Taylor and the chain rule,

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(p+tq)-f(p)}t=\frac{df(p+tq)}{dt}=f_x(p)q_x+f_y(p)q_y+f_z(p)q_z=\nabla f(p)\cdot q$$

where $\nabla f$ denotes a vector formed by the partial derivatives of $f$, which is called the gradient. This expresses that the linear part of the variation of $f$ is enough to evaluate the first order variation in any direction.

---

If you study the second order variations, you will get a quadratic form with a matrix formed with the second order derivatives, called the Hessian.

Comment: What confuses me is the application of the chain rule after the second equality. For example, if we use spherical coordinates, you can use similar arguments and reach the conclusion that the gradient is simply the partial derivatives with respect to $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$, which we know is not the case.

Comment: @user3612675: you should have asked that in the first place.

Comment: You are right. But I am not so interested in the derivation of the gradient in the spherical coordinates. I simply assumed that the same train of though can be used to derive the gradient for all coordinate systems. And by the way, I think that my initial comment was wrong. If you consider spherical coordinates, you will have $f_r(p)q_r + f_\theta(p)q_\theta + f_\phi(p)q_\phi$. But because the dot product between the basis vectors in spherical coordinates is not 1, the coefficients of the gradient would have to be scaled accordingly, and that would give you the correct form. Thanks